# findFragmentByTag returning null after performing replcae method of fragmenttransaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I am new in fragments. Can somebody help me?

I have a callback function which will be called everytime on a button click. In the below code Ist time execution everything works fine but after performing the transaction.replace method, firstfragment becomes null forever. As it is a callback function so this method will be called manytimes and eachtime as firstfragment becomes null so it will not execute transaction method(inside condition: if(firstfragment !=null)).
My code is as given below:

```
private void returnToFragmentB(){
        if (_provider != null)
        {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(firstfragment !=null)
                {
        classA obj = firstfragment.getdata();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment secondfragment = FragmentB.newInstance(_provider, null, obj.getdata1(), obj.getdata2());
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondfragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();   
        }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you are using the replace method, that means your first fragment is deleted and replaced, if you want to have both fragments you should use the add method and hide the first one.

Example

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
Fragment secondfragment = FragmentB.newInstance(_provider, null, obj.getdata1(), obj.getdata2());
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, secondfragment);
transaction.hide(yourFirstFragmentTAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the aove scenario but still I am getting the firstfragment=null. As per your suggestion, I used the firstfragment tag to hide it but no luck

Comment: Can anybody help me on it?

Comment: Can you post more of your code, like where are you defining and setting your firstfragment?